# can't pip install mysql-python

Tags: python, django, pip

I'm trying to get django/pip/mysql working and i can't seem to figure out how to install mysql-python. this is the error i receive when trying to install mysql-python

```
pip install mysql-python

Downloading/unpacking mysql-python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.4.zip (113kB): 113kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package mysql-python
    Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.28.tar.gz
    Extracting in /tmp/tmp5jjdpf
    Now working in /tmp/tmp5jjdpf/distribute-0.6.28
    Building a Distribute egg in /home/brian/flaskapp/build/mysql-python
    /home/brian/flaskapp/build/mysql-python/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg

Installing collected packages: mysql-python
  Running setup.py install for mysql-python
    building '_mysql' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,4,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.4 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fno-strict-aliasing -g -DNDEBUG
    _mysql.c:29:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /home/brian/flaskapp/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/brian/flaskapp/build/mysql-python/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Ur7r16-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /home/brian/flaskapp/include/site/python2.7:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

running build_ext

building '_mysql' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,4,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.4 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fno-strict-aliasing -g -DNDEBUG

_mysql.c:29:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /home/brian/flaskapp/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/brian/flaskapp/build/mysql-python/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Ur7r16-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /home/brian/flaskapp/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /home/brian/flaskapp/build/mysql-python
Storing complete log in /home/brian/.pip/pip.log
```

Googling reveals i need to install python-dev but whenever i try to install with

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

i get this error:

```
E: Package 'python-dev' has no installation candidate
```

I'm currently using linux mint 15 RC and i think that might be the issue...but i'm not sure. 
I'm out of ideas:(

Comment: I found this in a mint forum ... `sudo apt-get install python-all-dev`.  I have no idea what the names are on things in mint though, so I can't guarantee any success.

Comment: $ mysql_config The program 'mysql_config' is currently not installed. You can install it  by command here : sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

Comment: I want to point that running pip install mysql-python totally screwed up my project. In the end I decided to change my mysql database with a postresql one. see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56873213/django-db-utils-operationalerror-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-ha/56984704#56984704

Answer (score 53, accepted):

try downloading python-dev through software manager:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Comment: apt install python3-dev

Answer (score 5):

ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

Worked for me.

Comment: It will be helpful if you provide a solution rather than a work around.

Answer (score 0):

First create path as below by running into terminal

`export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH`

After doing this run following command to terminal

`sudo pip3 install flask-mysqldb`