# Error- Unable to install flask-mysql

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I tried installing mysql client for flask i get an error, I am using python 3.4. I have also tried installing mysql using pip install mysql same result.
`pip install flask-mysql`
If you have any questions please ask me  i have also tried upgrading the wheel and setup tools still it produce same result.

Console:

```
 Collecting flask-mysql
  Using cached Flask_MySQL-1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Flask in c:\python34\l
ib\site-packages (from flask-mysql)
Collecting MySQL-python (from flask-mysql)
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): click>=2.0 in c:\pytho
n34\lib\site-packages (from Flask->flask-mysql)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Werkzeug>=0.7 in c:\py
thon34\lib\site-packages (from Flask->flask-mysql)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): itsdangerous>=0.21 in
c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from Flask->flask-mysql)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Jinja2>=2.4 in c:\pyth
on34\lib\site-packages (from Flask->flask-mysql)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): MarkupSafe in c:\pytho
n34\lib\site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.4->Flask->flask-mysql)
Building wheels for collected packages: MySQL-python
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for MySQL-python ... error
  Complete output from command c:\python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools,
tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-z20yc1i6\\My
SQL-python\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).rea
d().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\DELL\AppD
ata\Local\Temp\tmprw0gh6vepip-wheel- --python-tag cp34:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\const
ants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\con
stants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\constants

  copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\consta
nts
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\constan
ts
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release
  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c
 /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version_
_=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\py
thon34\include -Ic:\python34\include /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Rel
ease\_mysql.obj /Zl
  _mysql.c
  _mysql.c(42) : fatal error C1083: Impossibile aprire il file inclusione 'confi
g-win.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\Bin
\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for MySQL-python
  Running setup.py clean for MySQL-python
Failed to build MySQL-python
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python, flask-mysql
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools
, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-z20yc1i6\\
MySQL-python\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).r
ead().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\DELL\
AppData\Local\Temp\pip-2r3_b720-record\install-record.txt --single-version-exter
nally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\con
stants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\constants

    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\c
onstants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\constants

    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\constan
ts
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\cons
tants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\const
ants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release
    c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\x86_amd64\cl.exe
/c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__versio
n__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\
python34\include -Ic:\python34\include /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\R
elease\_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
    _mysql.c(42) : fatal error C1083: Impossibile aprire il file inclusione 'con
fig-win.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\B
in\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\
\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-z20yc1i6\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';
exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\
n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-2
r3_b720-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile"
 failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-z20yc1i6
\MySQL-python\
```

Comment: Looks like your issue could be related to not having a proper Python development environment set up, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564745/cant-pip-install-mysql-python?rq=1

Comment: that was sad to see, no upvote for you for 4 years and so many people came to this page because they faced this issue.
I couldn't do much but here's an upvote. stay blessed

Answer (score 2):

Flask-mysql [does not have](https://github.com/cyberdelia/flask-mysql/issues/8) Python 3 support, see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/3ik1w7/flaskmysql_vs_flaskmysqldb/cuhn213). You can use [flask-mysqldb](https://github.com/admiralobvious/flask-mysqldb) which is tested and compatible with Python 3+.

Comment: The problem is with `MySQL-python` which does not [support](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5) Python 3. And there is the problem with building MySQL-python on [Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440230/install-mysql-python-windows).

Comment: flask-mysqldb uses [mysqlclient](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python) instead which solves that problem.

Comment: @dasdachs for the windows issue try [this](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python) binaries.