# error while installing mysql using pip (python)

Tags: django, windows-8, python-3.4

i'm new boy in python,
recently i am starting to understand Django,
for some basic functonality i have to use pip,
while i try to install some package using pip it Give error live Belove.
Thank you For Your Kind Responce.

```
C:\Users\Artoon>pip install mysql
Collecting mysql
Collecting MySQL-python (from mysql)
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: MySQL-python
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for MySQL-python ... error
  Complete output from command c:\paython36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Artoon\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-la79b8wq\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\Artoon\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpg_5j7u4fpip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\paython36\include -Ic:\paython36\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
  _mysql.c
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(192): warning C4005: 'isnan': macro redefinition
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\math.h(264): note: see previous definition of 'isnan'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(203): warning C4005: 'SIZEOF_OFF_T': macro redefinition
  c:\paython36\include\pyconfig.h(332): note: see previous definition of 'SIZEOF_OFF_T'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(301): warning C4005: 'HAVE_STDDEF_H': macro redefinition
  c:\paython36\include\pyconfig.h(675): note: see previous definition of 'HAVE_STDDEF_H'
  _mysql.c(287): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(297): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(317): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(327): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(470): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(623): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(624): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(625): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(626): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(627): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(1118): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(1161): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(1162): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(1165): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(1274): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(1466): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(1468): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(1504): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(1506): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(1532): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
  _mysql.c(2238): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from '_mysql_ConnectionObject *' to 'long'
  _mysql.c(2241): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from '_mysql_ConnectionObject *' to 'long'
  _mysql.c(2302): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from '__int64' to 'long', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(2321): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from '_mysql_ResultObject *' to 'long'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\lib\opt" /LIBPATH:c:\paython36\libs /LIBPATH:c:\paython36\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64" kernel32.lib advapi32.lib wsock32.lib mysqlclient.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__mysql build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_mysql.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\_mysql.cp36-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_mysql.cp36-win_amd64.lib
  _mysql.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit__mysql' specified multiple times; using first specification
     Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_mysql.cp36-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_mysql.cp36-win_amd64.exp
  mysqlclient.lib(typelib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
  mysqlclient.lib(viosslfactories.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
  mysqlclient.lib(my_winfile.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
  mysqlclient.lib(my_messnc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
  mysqlclient.lib(client.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
  mysqlclient.lib(my_thr_init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
  mysqlclient.lib(my_init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
  mysqlclient.lib(default.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
  build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\_mysql.cp36-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for MySQL-python
  Running setup.py clean for MySQL-python
Failed to build MySQL-python
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python, mysql
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python ... error
    Complete output from command c:\paython36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Artoon\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-la79b8wq\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Artoon\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-a7xacs6e-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\paython36\include -Ic:\paython36\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(192): warning C4005: 'isnan': macro redefinition
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\math.h(264): note: see previous definition of 'isnan'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(203): warning C4005: 'SIZEOF_OFF_T': macro redefinition
    c:\paython36\include\pyconfig.h(332): note: see previous definition of 'SIZEOF_OFF_T'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(301): warning C4005: 'HAVE_STDDEF_H': macro redefinition
    c:\paython36\include\pyconfig.h(675): note: see previous definition of 'HAVE_STDDEF_H'
    _mysql.c(287): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(297): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(317): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(327): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(470): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(623): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(624): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(625): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(626): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(627): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(1118): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(1161): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(1162): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(1165): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(1274): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(1466): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(1468): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(1504): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(1506): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(1532): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
    _mysql.c(2238): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from '_mysql_ConnectionObject *' to 'long'
    _mysql.c(2241): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from '_mysql_ConnectionObject *' to 'long'
    _mysql.c(2302): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from '__int64' to 'long', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(2321): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from '_mysql_ResultObject *' to 'long'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\lib\opt" /LIBPATH:c:\paython36\libs /LIBPATH:c:\paython36\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64" kernel32.lib advapi32.lib wsock32.lib mysqlclient.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__mysql build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_mysql.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\_mysql.cp36-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_mysql.cp36-win_amd64.lib
    _mysql.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit__mysql' specified multiple times; using first specification
       Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_mysql.cp36-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_mysql.cp36-win_amd64.exp
    mysqlclient.lib(typelib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(viosslfactories.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(my_winfile.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(my_messnc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(client.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(my_thr_init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(my_init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(default.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
    build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\_mysql.cp36-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\paython36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Artoon\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-la79b8wq\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Artoon\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-a7xacs6e-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Artoon\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-la79b8wq\MySQL-python\
```

Comment: Looks pretty similar to your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564745/cant-pip-install-mysql-python?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

i got it,
Remove All Version Of python,
And Install 2.7 , pip,
Then Dowanload

**

> MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win32.whl

**

from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python

and run command As Belove

> **pip install MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win32.whl**