# ERROR :: Installing MySql using pip in windows

Tags: python, sql, pip

I want to connect python with MySQL database but I'm stucked just because of this.This is the command I made:       `pip install mysql`    but after that sql was not installed and What I had was this error. Can anyone suggest me what to do??

```
Collecting mysql
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/06/ef/c4efbf2a51fb46aba9be03a973638d9539c9ca10a5259b2cbb1a66133b2e/mysql-0.0.1.tar.gz
Collecting MySQL-python (from mysql)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python, mysql
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python ... error
    Complete output from command "c:\users\kuldeep sharma\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\KULDEE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cc8pga51\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\KULDEE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0d1bgkuf\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\users\kuldeep sharma\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\KULDEE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cc8pga51\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\KULDEE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0d1bgkuf\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\KULDEE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cc8pga51\MySQL-python\
```

Comment: Possible answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283988/error-while-installing-mysql-using-pip-python Take a look here and see if this helps it hasnt got an accepted answer however see if the answer written works :)

Comment: I'm not using Django, how it can be a duplicate. I'll check there may be answer which can support

Comment: Hense why i said maybe the answer could help you