# Error while installing mysql-python using pip

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, installation, pip, macos-sierra

Get the following error while installing mysql-python using pip

pip  : 9.0.1

python : 2.7

OS : Mac OS Sierra 10.12.5

```
    Some-MacBook-Air:~ itssuyog$ pip install mysql-python
Collecting mysql-python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 257kB/s
Installing collected packages: mysql-python
  Running setup.py install for mysql-python ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/hm/jbqvwv_n1sb46q_v9wvb3fh80000gp/T/pip-build-ThTb9v/mysql-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/hm/jbqvwv_n1sb46q_v9wvb3fh80000gp/T/pip-jTh4C4-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed--compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7
    cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.2.7_1/include/mysql -I/usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.2.7_1/include/mysql/.. -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/_mysql.o
    In file included from _mysql.c:44:
    /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.2.7_1/include/mysql/my_config.h:286:11: warning: 'SIZEOF_SIZE_T' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
      #define SIZEOF_SIZE_T  SIZEOF_LONG
              ^
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pymacconfig.h:43:17: note: previous definition is here
    #        define SIZEOF_SIZE_T           8
                    ^
    _mysql.c:287:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    cmd_argc = PySequence_Size(cmd_args);
                             ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:317:12: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    groupc = PySequence_Size(groups);
                           ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:470:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                            int j, n2=PySequence_Size(fun);
                                   ~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1127:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    len = mysql_real_escape_string(&(self->connection), out, in, size);
                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1129:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    len = mysql_escape_string(out, in, size);
                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1168:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            size = PyString_GET_SIZE(s);
                 ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/stringobject.h:92:32: note: expanded from macro 'PyString_GET_SIZE'
    #define PyString_GET_SIZE(op)  Py_SIZE(op)
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/object.h:116:56: note: expanded from macro 'Py_SIZE'
    #define Py_SIZE(ob)             (((PyVarObject*)(ob))->ob_size)
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1178:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    len = mysql_real_escape_string(&(self->connection), out+1, in, size);
                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1180:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    len = mysql_escape_string(out+1, in, size);
                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1274:11: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            if ((n = PyObject_Length(o)) == -1) goto error;
                   ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/abstract.h:434:25: note: expanded from macro 'PyObject_Length'
    #define PyObject_Length PyObject_Size
                            ^
    _mysql.c:1466:10: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                            len = strlen(buf);
                                ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1468:10: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                            len = strlen(buf);
                                ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1504:11: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                    len = strlen(buf);
                                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1506:11: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                    len = strlen(buf);
                                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1589:10: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
            if (how < 0 || how >= sizeof(row_converters)) {
                ~~~ ^ ~
    _mysql.c:2005:42: error: no member named 'reconnect' in 'struct st_mysql'
            if ( reconnect != -1 ) self->connection.reconnect = reconnect;
                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
    15 warnings and 1 error generated.
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/hm/jbqvwv_n1sb46q_v9wvb3fh80000gp/T/pip-build-ThTb9v/mysql-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/hm/jbqvwv_n1sb46q_v9wvb3fh80000gp/T/pip-jTh4C4-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/hm/jbqvwv_n1sb46q_v9wvb3fh80000gp/T/pip-build-ThTb9v/mysql-python/
```

I got a similar post on Stack Overflow :  [can't pip install mysql-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564745/cant-pip-install-mysql-python)

That is for Ubuntu. But still I tried to install `python-dev` as suggested in the answer of that post using pip and got the following error :

```
Some-MacBook-Air:~ itssuyog$ sudo pip install python-dev
Password:
The directory '/Users/admin/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/admin/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check thepermissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting python-dev
  Downloading python-dev-4.1.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-mFlFdp/python-dev/setup.py", line 90, in <module>
        evalall()
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-mFlFdp/python-dev/setup.py", line 86, in evalall
        print("安装完成!")
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-mFlFdp/python-dev/
```

Thanx in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

[python-dev](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dev) is the wrong python-dev; it seems some rogue Chineeze took the name and created a package that installs a backdoor.

Real python-dev is a development package for Debian/Ubuntu installable with `apt`. You don't need it in MacOS. If you have done `brew install python` (or `python3`) you should already have all necessary development files.

Try [installing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25865271/7976758) mysql-connector:

```
brew install mysql-connector-c
```

Comment: I installed `mysql-connector-c` as suggested, but still, I am not able install `mysql-python`. 


Getting following error :


`Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/hm/jbqvwv_n1sb46q_v9wvb3fh80000gp/T/pip-build-wkqNtY/mysql-python/`