# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'handshake: reading inital communication packet', system error: 0")

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am developing an app in django to push it on Heroku, and while trying to migrate a database in mysql to heroku, I pip installed mysql-python and as I try to run the server, I got this error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL
> server at 'handshake: reading inital communication packet', system
> error: 0")

(I had my virtual environment on).
The strange thing is that the package installed python even if I had that already installed.
 I found out that it unistalled django and several modules I previously installed, even pip!

I re-installed the modules but now as I run the server I get that error above.
If I run the server from another app directory, the database runs fine.
Is it maybe related to something I had installed in my directory and maybe was apparently overwritten by the strange package?

here is my pip freeze result:

```
certifi==2019.6.16
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.2.3
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
mysql-connector-python==8.0.16
mysqlclient==1.4.2.post1
protobuf==3.6.0
psycopg2==2.8.3
PyMySQL==0.9.3
python-decouple==3.1
pytz==2019.1
six==1.12.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
whitenoise==4.1.2
wincertstore==0.2
```

I will now delete the project and try to rebuild it anew, as long as I understand, what screw up the project was my attempt to install mysql-python.

```
Collecting mysql-python   Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip Building wheels for collected packages: mysql-python   Building wheel for mysql-python (setup.py) ... error   ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Anaconda3\envs\met3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Tommaso\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yr8h0ec1\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Tommaso\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ywwxryy8' --python-tag cp37:   ERROR: running bdist_wheel   running build   running build_py  creating build   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7   copying
_mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb   copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb   copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb   copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb   copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb   copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb   copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants   copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants   copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants   copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants   copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants   copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants   copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants   copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants   running build_ext   building '_mysql' extension   creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7   creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1)
-D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -IC:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Anaconda3\envs\met3\include -IC:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Anaconda3\envs\met3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\cppwinrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl   _mysql.c  
_mysql.c(42): fatal error C1083: Non è possibile aprire il file inclusione: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory   error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2   ----------------------------------------   ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysql-python   Running setup.py clean for mysql-python Failed to build mysql-python Installing collected packages: mysql-python   Running setup.py install for mysql-python ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Anaconda3\envs\met3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Tommaso\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yr8h0ec1\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Tommaso\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dwqliwhp\install-record.txt'
--single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1)
-D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -IC:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Anaconda3\envs\met3\include -IC:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Anaconda3\envs\met3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\cppwinrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
    _mysql.c(42): fatal error C1083: Non è possibile aprire il file inclusione: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command "'C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Anaconda3\envs\met3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Tommaso\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yr8h0ec1\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Tommaso\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dwqliwhp\install-record.txt'
--single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Tommaso\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yr8h0ec1\mysql-python\
```

---

**UPDATE**

The bad command, that is,

> pip install mysql-python

had set my python default path to 2.7 instead of 3.7.

To fix it, I had to (Windows 10):

Cortana > search bar > type "env" > change environment variables for the system > environment variables > select "Path" > change >

create and move to the top (or simply move to the top) the path in which you have installed python 3.7.

Save > close anaconda.
This made pyhton and its modules work again.
I had to reinstall pip, now it works again.
But when my virtual environment is on, I have problems with my connected database in mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

After fixing thing as I decribed in the question update,
I found out that Heroku has some problems to manage mysql database, even if connected with the add-on ClearDB.

So I changed the database from mysql to Postgresql, thus not needing the `mysql-python` modules anymore.
This made me not stumble anymore in the previous conflicts between Django and Heroku.

In the end it turned out that trying to

```
pip install mysql-python
```

was the thing that completely screwed up my project.
I had all the installed modules removed from my computer:
pip, conda, python, django...

Answer (score 0):

It might be a `Firewall` issue. Make sure the port you are running MySQL is open for inbound traffic from the `IP` where your `App` is running.

Comment: No, it is not, I checked.