# Mysql Connector 8.0 and Python 3.8

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I am using Windows 10. I have python 3.8.2 32 bit installed. I am trying to use mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.20.0.msi the connector for Python. The connectors are grayed out and not available. The error message says Python 32-bit not installed. I see old threads claiming you need Python 3.4. The documentation here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-versions.html claims this will work with Python 3.8.2. Do I need a different MySql installer? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Do you have the `python` executable in your PATH? That is, when you open a terminal or *command line* window and type `python --version`, do you see the version string or do you get an error like *command not found*?

Comment: yes, I can run python from the command line.

Comment: Your CPU is 64 bit or 32 bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why I was using the MySQL installer to install libraries for Python. In hind-sight, that doesn't make sense. Use pip to install the drivers like

```
$ pip install mysql-connector-python
# or
$ python pip install mysql-connector
# or for >= Python 3.9
$ pip install mysqlclient
```

It is not entirely clear what the difference is, but, the first of the three solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue while working with MySQL 8.0.18 with Python 3.8 on Windows 10 64 Bit Machine.

And I used the following workaround -

1. Ensured that all the installers used were 64-Bits installers for My SQL and Python since my machine is Windows 10 64-bit machine.
2. Ensured that Python Connector for MySQL supported the corresponding python version from https://insidemysql.com/category/mysql-development/connectors/python/ Incase of issues or lack of information downgraded MySql by minor version.
3. Downloaded independent MSI for Connector from - [dev.mysql.com/downloads](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/)
4. Manually installed the downloaded Connector MSI.

Hopefully this information will help you troubleshoot your issue as well by using corresponding 32-bit versions.

Answer (score 0):

It is sadly known that MYSQL has low compatibility with python.

For example, I have stepped into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56873213/django-db-utils-operationalerror-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-ha/56984704#56984704) while trying to install `mysql-python` (a terrible one!) and [this other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54633968/2059-authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-when-running-server-conne) while using `mysqlclient`.

There are a lot of python connectors for mysql, you can try some and see one by one if they work. I would recommend [pymysql](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/).

However, I would recommend you to use a Postgresql db with python, it really works like charm, and if you want to have a local DBMS/GUI/workbench to work on it, you can use PgAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

If your CPU architecture is 64 bit then be sure that you download MySQL Connector 64 bit version. 32 bit installers would also work but sometimes occurs minor errors. Also MySQL Connector Python requires Python to be in the system’s `PATH`. Installation fails if python cannot be located. Add python.exe path to System PATH varible. So that MySQL connector can find the execution file.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why I was using the MySQL installer to install libraries for Python. In hind-sight, that doesn't make sense. Use pip to install the drivers like

```
$ pip install mysql-connector-python
# or
$ python pip install mysql-connector
```

It is not entirely clear what the difference is, but, the first of the two solved the problem.

Adarsh