# Django2.2.7 + Mysqlclient installation error + Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have successfully installed python3.6.* and Django2.2.*, MySQL-server However in the virtualenv I am getting error while installing the MySQL client.

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,4,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.4 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I/var/www/venv/include/python3.6m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /var/www/venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-fezj4ikj/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-fezj4ikj/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-kodyrb_q/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /var/www/venv/include/site/python3.6/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.
```

Command I follow

```
sudo apt install python3
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip install virtualenv
pip install mysqlclient
```

Does anyone have help guide to resolve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't pip install mysql-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564745/cant-pip-install-mysql-python)